# Printing ascii art mirrored horizontally using c#

Tags: c#, ascii

I am trying to print ASCII art for a project. This is what it looks like:

``````````````
var array = new string[]
        {
                @"   ```````     `..`.``            ``.``.`         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     -ooooo+            :ooooo/         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     -ooooo+            :oooso:         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     .+oo++/            :++oo+:         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     `......```..```.```......`         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     `.`......`..``..``.....`.`         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     `.........`....`.........`         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     /mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm+.....`         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     /MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM+`....`         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     /MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM+.....`         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     .+++++oMMMMMMo++//+-`....`         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     ``...`-MMMMMM-....`......`         ",
                @"   +ooooo-     ``...`-MMMMMM-...........`         ",
                @"   ::::::.``````......ssssss/::::::::::::----:-   ",
                @"   `....................`...+ooooooooooooooooo+   ",
                @"   `...............`........ooooooo+oooooooooo+   ",
                @"   `````````````............+ooooo+/////+ooooo+   ",
                @"               `.....`.....`+oooo+:.`...:ooooo+   ",
                @"               `............+ooooo:````.:ooooo+   ",
                @"               ``....`..`...+ooooo:.....:ooooo+   ",
                @"               `....``...`..+ooooooooooooooooo+   ",
                @"               `............oooooooooooooooooo+   ",
                @"               `......````..++++++oooooo++oo++/   ",
                @"               `...```      ```````.....``````    ",
                @"               `.....`            `....``         ",
                @"               `.....`            `.``.``         "
        };
foreach (string line in arr)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
``````````````

So far it's working, but I wanted to  be able to print it mirrored horizontally, like that:

Mirrored image:

[image]

I can't figure out a way to do it. I've tried Array.Reverse, but it prints the image upside down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your self an extension method to reverse a string, that way you can iterate through your array, and reverse each line separately

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Reverse(this string s)
    {
        var charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string (charArray);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
foreach (string line in array)
    Console.WriteLine(line.Reverse());
```

**Output**

``````````````
         `.``.``            ``.`..`     ```````   
         /ooooo:            +ooooo-     -ooooo+   
         :osooo:            +ooooo-     -ooooo+   
         :+oo++:            /++oo+.     -ooooo+   
         `......```.```..```......`     -ooooo+   
         `.`.....``..``..`......`.`     -ooooo+   
         `.........`....`.........`     -ooooo+   
         `.....+mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm/     -ooooo+   
         `....`+MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM/     -ooooo+   
         `.....+MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM/     -ooooo+   
         `....`-+//++oMMMMMMo+++++.     -ooooo+   
         `......`....-MMMMMM-`...``     -ooooo+   
         `...........-MMMMMM-`...``     -ooooo+   
   -:----::::::::::::/ssssss......``````.::::::   
   +ooooooooooooooooo+...`....................`   
   +oooooooooo+ooooooo........`...............`   
   +ooooo+/////+ooooo+............`````````````   
   +ooooo:...`.:+oooo+`.....`.....`               
   +ooooo:.````:ooooo+............`               
   +ooooo:.....:ooooo+...`..`....``               
   +ooooooooooooooooo+..`...``....`               
   +oooooooooooooooooo............`               
   /++oo++oooooo++++++..````......`               
    ``````.....```````      ```...`               
         ``....`            `.....`               
         ``.``.`            `.....`
``````````````

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZglU31)

Comment: You forgot to add `line.Reverse()` in your demo. don't worry i'd fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.Reverse` does not make your array reversed, but instead it returns a reversed version of your array. So simply set it as a new variable and print it :

```
foreach (string line in arr.Reverse())
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```